# Регулярное выражение для выделения дробных чисел

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Напишите регулярное выражение, которое выделяет в тексте только дробные числа, а целые не выделяет.

```
Input: 8.73 1 12
Output: 8.73
```

Comment: `\d+\.\d+` наверное так)

Comment: Да, сработало!!! Спасибо, ThisMan!

Comment: `\d+\.\d+` найдёт `1.3` в строке `1.3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вот так:

```
\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*
```

Answer (score -3):

```
/[1-9]+\.[1-9]+/ - если нужно только первое число найти,
/[1-9]+\.[1-9]+/g - если нужно все числа
```

Comment: дробные числа могут содержать цифру `0`!

Comment: type(1.) и type(.5) ?

Comment: Спасибо, решение ThisMan оказалось верным.